# CDP filter Network requests - Puppteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to get timing of a specific network request with Puppteer.

Is there any way to filter requests from Chrome DevTools Protocol in Puppteer, so that `responseReceived` will be fired only when this specific network response is received?

My actual code for this task is:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.enable');

// this method is deprecated and I don't know if it was the right thing to use ( https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-setRequestInterception )
await client.send('Network.setRequestInterception', {
    patterns: [
        {
            urlPattern: 'https://www.example.com/*task=customaction*',
            resourceType: 'XHR',
            interceptionStage: 'HeadersReceived'
        }
    ]
});

client.on('responseReceived', (requestId, loaderId, timestamp, type, response, frameId) => {
    console.log(`Debug data from: ${response.url} (${requestId})`)
    console.log('Timing:')
    console.log(response.timing)
    detach()
})
```

The documentation suggests to use Fetch as replacement of `Network.setRequestInterception`(https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch), but it looks like that Fetch Domain propose is  modify network requests.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late and hope you already solved this. However, posting so that anyone can benefit this.

You can take help of metrics as shown in [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagemetrics)